# How to handle bucket paths that contain "." with gsutil

Tags: amazon-s3, gsutil

I am referencing a s3 bucket path that contains a period with Gsutil that is producing the below error

"Failure: hostname u'example.feed.s3.amazonaws.com' doesn't match either of '*.s3.amazonaws.com', 's3.amazonaws.com'."

When i reference a bucket path without a period everything works as expected.  How do i reference S3 bucket paths that contain periods?

not working properly:
gsutil ls s3://example.feed

working properly:
gsutil ls s3://examplefeed

I've attempted to escape characters but that dosn't seem to be working